# Atom 1.54.0 wont launch on Ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor, launch

After updating to 1.54.0, atom doesn't launch on Ubuntu 20. I used
'''
snap revert atom
'''
to get the previous version.

Does anybody know why it does not launch?

Answer (score 0):

you can use from dpkg -L atom for see library installed for atom and check what library have confilict for version in your ubuntu.
i dont have any confuse in installed atom 1.54 so you installed a package with confilict with this version of atom.